# Scroll between multiple workspaces?

Tags: 16.04

Is there any program that allow one to scroll between the different workspace (partially)? Quick switching I find is not as good since I still prefer to see the part of the different workspaces side-by-side if possible.  Actually kind of surprised no OS seems to have this feature AFAIK.

I am on default Unity/16.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

You can press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to show all workspaces at once.

Comment: While that's interesting but it's not what I was looking for.

Comment: OK. I wasn't sure if it was, but figured it's worth mentioning.